# On report developing using SQL Server Reporting MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying design a report where the report would have the below fields with data.
The relation is each test_id has n number of documents,so i am trying a drop down at each test_id.

When i click on the plus sign(+),it opens up the drop drown and lists all individual entries for the test_id.

I know we need to group by the coulmn and I have done so on the column Test_id,the report preview displays data but it isnt
proper.
Hence requesting all that I want to know how to make the drop down working properly from the basic start.

```
#Test_id#         #Document_id#       #DocumentName#
   1                10                ScannedDoc
                    11                Handwritten

   2                100                Imagefile
                    111                WordDoc
```

Comment: You are correct in that you want to group on Test_id. If it "isn't proper", you'll need to post more information so that we can help you.

Comment: Thanks.How could I post a screenprint or image here to show whats displaying for me? And I actually want in a different way.It would be very helpful if you could help please